# Writing a number of bytes to a GLib.OutputStream in Vala

Tags: networking, pointers, glib, vala, gio

I'm currently writing an application using Vala that requires me to send data over a network.  To aid in creating the packets (and updating the protocol at later dates), I have created structures that I am passing to a method as void*.  These structures represent how the packet is arranged and allow me to very easily generate a packet to send without having to mess around too much.  The problem with this, however, is that the Vala wrapper for GLib.OutputStream.write() doesn't accept a count (even though the original method does).  Vala takes the size of the uint8[] passed to it and provides that to the original method.  Is there a simple way of getting around this, sans editing the GIO vapi?  Possibly a very cheap way of casting a void* to a uint8[] while supplying a size?  I'm aiming for very high performance here as the application will be required to maintain thousands of connections simultaneously.  Thanks in advance for any help.

~ Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using a macro like this:

```
#define OBJECT_TO_BUFFER(val,type,size) (*(size) = sizeof(type), (guint8*)val)
```

To get around this problem. It takes your object and simply returns the same memory as an `uint8[]`. It has the corresponding prototype in Vala:

```
unowned uint8[] Buffer.of<T>(ref T @value);
```

The header files and VAPI file called “tricks” are [in my GitHub](https://github.com/apmasell/vapis/blob/master/tricks.vapi). There are similar versions for dealing with arrays of objects.

Comment: Thank you :)  I'll give these a try.  Is there no way to do it all via Vala, though?  I mean, I don't mind using a header as it's only really me that's going to be using the code.  I'm just wondering if it can be done without the need of C code :)

Answer (score 1):

```
unowned uint8[] buf = (uint8[]) your_real_buffer;
buf.length = the_length_you_want;
```

Then send buf.